# Static factory methods and static objects memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, static-methods, delete-operator

I have a class with a static factory constructor which returns a pointer to the object created.

I have to declare the object as a static object inside a namespace but I don't know how to delete it correctly

```
class Foo
{
   public:
   Foo(int, int* );
   virtual ~Foo();
   static Foo* MyFooInitializer(int n )
   {
      int *p = new int[n];
      for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
         p[i]=i;

      Foo *ret = new Foo(n,p);
      delete p;
      return ret;
   }
   int someFooFunction(int a);
}
```

Then in my namespace I have a `static inline` function

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    static inline void  myfunction()
    {
        static Foo  *foo1 = Foo::MyFooInitializer(10); 
        int y = somevalue();
        int x = foo1->someFooFunction(int y);
    } 
}
```

I obviously have a memory leak here because the object is never deleted.

The important fact is that I need that foo1 is declared as static because once created it must be the same object during all the program and must be unique (it keeps track of some variables).

Probably this is a design problem, but I don't know how to delete it when my program exits or when I explicitly want to delete it to reinitialize it.

**SOLUTION:**

I modified the body of `MyFooInitializer` this way:

```
   static Foo* MyFooInitializer(int n )
   {
      int *p = new int[n];
      for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
         p[i]=i;

      static Foo ret = Foo(n,p);
      delete[] p;
      return &ret;
   }
```

This allows me to release all the memory correctly when the program terminates. Valgrind says all the heap memory is freed!

Comment: You haven't used `new()` anywhere so why do you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: @Als I bet there's a new in `MyFooInitializer`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It could very well be a local `static` instance which always remains alive throughout the program lifetime.And if it is not, just replace the `new` with one and then there's no leak :)

Comment: What is "g" in your function? Why are you initializing "p" and then just deleting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for allocating that Foo on the heap here:

```
static Foo* MyFooInitializer(int x) {
    static Foo some_foo(x);
    return &some_foo;
}
```

There are no leaks in that code, that Foo will be destroyed when your program ends.

Note that if the pointer returned by `MyFooInitializer` actually points to some class which inherits from `Foo`, then you'd just have to use the derived type for the static variable:

```
static Foo* MyFooInitializer(int x) {
    static SomeFooDerived some_foo(x);
    return &some_foo;
}
```

**Edit**: Since you provided the actual function body, my answer is valid. You'd do it like this:

```
static Foo* MyFooInitializer(int n ) {
   // Don't know what this p is, anyway...
   int *p = new int[n];
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
      p[i]=i;

   static Foo ret(n,g); // what is g?
   delete[] p; // smart pointer plx
   return &ret;
}
```

Comment: And thus we've come to the Singleton Pattern.

Comment: +1 For *"There is no need for allocating that Foo on the heap"*. This is very true.

Comment: Yes, it's basically a singleton. There is no need to allocate on the heap for every call to MyFooInitializer, since you already know that the lifetime of that object will last till the end of the application.

Comment: beware of static deinitialization fiasco! If a static object A accesses a static object B during destruction, make sure B is constructed before A.

Comment: We actually don't know if he CAN do it via singleton. Maybe the parameter or even the type returned from classfactory is not known until runtime.

Comment: @Agent_L well, if OP doesn't provide more code, we can't start assuming things. This will work most of the time. Maybe if OP provided his current "MyFooInitializer" code, the solutions could be more accurate.

Comment: @linello Ok, there you go. I still don't know what half of your function body does, but I believe that my first approach was correct.

Comment: @linello You got all the answers. You have to decide now. Is the foo the only instance in your entire program - Use Singleton, as here. Are there some other foo's - use my solution. And btw, you don't need class factory at all, you can do all the work in foo's ctor.

Comment: Right, I modified the MyFooInitializer as mfontanin said and now I get no leak at all!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
static inline void  myfunction()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo1(Foo::MyFooInitializer(10));
    int y = somevalue();
    int x = foo1->someFooFunction(int y);
}
```

Comment: I don't find unique_ptr (I'm writing C++ O3 compliant). I'm writing my code with g++-4.4 and it must compile on g++ >= 4.0 and windows, it seems that unique_ptr is not here in standard headers <memory>.
Where can I find it? (i can't use boost).

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to create the foo1 dynamically, then write an extra class and make it static/global by value. Then use it's destructor to delete object(s).

```
class MasterControlClass
{
    public:
    Foo* foo1;
    MasterControl(){foo1 = NULL;}
    ~MasterControl(){delete(foo1), foo1 = NULL;}
};



static inline void myfunction()
{
     static MasterControlClass mcp;
     mcp.foo1 = Foo::MyFooInitializer(10); 
}
```

In this way, when your program is closing, the mcp desctructor will get called and will do the cleanup.
If you want to reinitialize, then ofc you have to delete foo1 at every assign, just add

```
if(mcp.foo1)
{
    delete mcp.foo1;
    mcp.foo1= NULL;
}
```

Or even better, move it to a method of mcp.